# How to fix this trivial thing I hate but cannot describe briefly?

Tags: xubuntu, gedit

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04 currently, but this has been bugging me for **years**.

So I make some changes in a new doc and go to save it:

[image]

The selected text, **Untitled Document 1**, is making it very clear by any UX standard that the next things I type will replace that text, right?

Well, no:

[image]

It starts searching for the nonexistent document I want to save??? I catches me out every time; I type the name, hit `save` and then find I've saved **Untitled Document 1**!  Grrr!

Is this configurable?  Does it annoy no one else?

I don't know enough about Linux application development, but I'm guessing that this "file save" dialog is part of a C- language app. dev. framework.  Which one?  Where's the source, so I can post an issue, or see if anyone else has posted an issue?

I fear I'll be down voted for whining about something that bothers no one else, but after 10 years of tripping over this thing just seldom enough to get caught by it every single time, I am curious to know what others think.

**update** (same day):  Very appreciative of all the supportive comments!  **Thank you!**

There seems to a related issue to do with visibility of buttons.  In my case, I am very use to being able to do, simply:

```
<ctrl-s>
navigate to target directory
type doc name
<enter>
```

If I am on a roll, I scarcely look at what I type, certainly don't want to HAVE to look at what I type.

ALSO!  As discussed in the comments, this occurs *only if* I navigate to the destination directory!

Comment: I don't use Xubuntu, so does this happen with just gedit or all file saving dialogues?

Comment: I can confirm that it's a similar behaviour on Ubuntu 20.04 - sometimes it searches for the file instead of renaming. The file picker is called Nautilus. So you might have luck looking for issues there.

Comment: Very annoying, I wonder why the Devs have never fixed this! Also, when you do select the box `untitled document 1` It un-selects the entire text and you must backspace every character to type your actual save name.

Comment: It's a known bug. Some possible solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533192/save-as-with-gedit)

Comment: @larsl The file picker is not nautilus, it is the GTK3 file dialog, from the GTK3 toolkit. I do not see the issue in standard Ubuntu (20.10), so this is something that might have been corrected.

Comment: See this bug report, which relates to this behaviour, but only when you first selected a different directory. However, you indicate you cannot change the name as soon as the dialog opens? https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/326

Comment: I experience this behavior in Ubuntu (Gnome) 20.04. @vanadium is right about this being a GTK3 file chooser issue (not Nautilus).

Comment: @PJSingh, immediately when you open the dialog or only if you first changed folders in the part below? If yes, then that may be an aspect  that is fixed in 20.10. If no, then what OP reports may just correspond with the bug I linked to, and which is still there in 20.10.

Comment: @vanadium, only after I change folder, as you described above. The bug report you linked to is still Open. You say this is this fixed in 20.10+?

Comment: Thanks for confirming: that indeed is the bug that still exists. I just await reaction whether also for the original poster, the problem only occurs after changing a folder, or immediately.

Comment: @vanadium  Your deep knowledge impresses me!  You are correct, the issue is *only if* I have changed to a different target directory.  Very grateful for your participation!

Comment: I daresay I don't only have it on Gnome 3 Ubuntu 20.04, but I had either this or something extremely similar on Unity 7 Ubuntu 16.04 too.

Comment: This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/439239)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you describe is know for many years and [reported here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/326). When the dialog is open, and the user changes the directory in the folder list, the keyboard focus has changed to that folder list, but the name field still stays highlighted as if it would still be selected.

That keyboard focus changes in this case, is *expected*. Otherwise, you would not be able to navigate that part of the dialog with the keyboard. What is *not right* is that the name stays highlighted.

There is a keyboard accelerator to return focus to the name field. Thus, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to quickly return to the name field. Hopefully, the misleading highlight issue will be solved, perhaps in GTK4?